# OCaml functor Set.Make/Map.Make weird annotation in VSCode

Tags: ocaml, functor

[image]

Why in the world is there a `/1.` between `Ord: Set` and `OrderedType ->` ?

This shows up for `Set.Make` and for `Map.Make` in VSCode environment, and possibly for other built-in `Make` functors as well.

See code below for an example, if you hover over the Set.Make function in VSCode, it will say as the first line "functor (Ord : Set/1.OrderedType)".

```
type t = { street : string; city : string }

module Address = struct
  type t = { street : string; city : string }

  let compare a1 a2 =
    match compare a1.city a2.city with
    | 0 -> compare a1.street a2.street
    | x -> x
end

module AddressSet = Set.Make (Address)
```

Comment: Mind sharing a minimal sample of code where this shows up?

Comment: I have read the OCaml specifications and didn't find a trace of a possible "1/". A bug ?

Comment: @FrédéricLOYER note that the screenshot shows `/1.` rather than `1/.`. I've corrected that in the question.

Comment: Please [post the code as text, not a painting of it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1048572)!

Comment: Just posted a short code snippet that replicates the thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pending information from Yanny, this looks like you've either redefined the module or VSCode is being proactive. Consider the following simple example:

```
% rlwrap ocaml
OCaml version 5.0.0~rc1
Enter #help;; for help.

# module type S = sig
    type t
  end
  
  module A (T : S) = struct
    type t = T.t
  end;;
module type S = sig type t end
module A : functor (T : S) -> sig type t = T.t end
# module B = A (Int)
  
  let foo (x: B.t) = x + 1;;
module B : sig type t = Int.t end
val foo : B.t -> int = <fun>
# module B = A (Float)
  
  let bar (x : B.t) = x +. 1.;;
module B : sig type t = Float.t end
val bar : B.t -> float = <fun>
# foo;;
- : B/2.t -> int = <fun>
```

Note the `B/2` designation for the type in the signature for `foo`? This is because I've shadowed the name `B` for the earlier module, but `foo` still has access to it.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! I was not able to actually replicate your process on my end, I used utop on my M1 Mac and what I got at the end was simply
foo;; 
 -:  int -> int

Comment: I didn't use utop but rather `rlwrap ocaml`.

Comment: Got it, still, I think you're right that this is the reason. Thank you so much!

Comment: I just installed rlwrap and after running your code above, I tried the following
`# module B = A (Bool)
  let w (x: B.t) = x & true;;`
Then, for w, I got `B.t -> bool = <fun>`, for foo I got `B/2.t -> int = <fun>`, and for bar I also got `B/2.t -> float = <fun>`. It seems that foo's t and bar's t are not distinguished apart?